# How do I insert more that one triple in a Marklogic JSON document?

Tags: javascript, json, semantic-web, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to insert some triples, via Javascript (query console), into a JSON document of the form

```
declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentInsert('/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article.json',
{
  "triple" : {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/author",
    "object" : "jasonmoore"
  },
  "triple" : {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/id",
    "object" : "automation_article2"
  },
  "triple" : {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/dateCreated",
    "object" : "2015-08-14 09:38:10 GMT-7:00"
  },
  "content" : {
  . . .
  }
});
```

However, when I look in the newly created document, only the last triple is there, the other two are missing.

What do I need to do to get the first two triples in the same document?

Comment: you can only have one key with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JSON object stores key-value pairs. The keys are unique.

```js
var obj = {
  a : 'This is a property, but it will be overwritten',
  a : 'Im really the value of a property'
};

console.log(obj);
```

That's the same to say :

```js
var obj = {
  a : 'This is a property, but it will be overwritten'
};

obj['a'] = 'Im really the value of a property';

console.log(obj);
```

Now you can think what's happening: Everytime you try to insert in the key `"triple"` is overwritting what it contains, and the value that finally stores is the last one.

```js
var myDbObject = {};
var obj = {
  "triple" : {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/author",
    "object" : "jasonmoore"
  },
  "triple" : {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/id",
    "object" : "automation_article2"
  },
  "triple" : {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/dateCreated",
    "object" : "2015-08-14 09:38:10 GMT-7:00"
  }
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>{
  myDbObject[key] = obj[key];
});

console.log(myDbObject);
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried to add this as a comment, but it won't format it with line breaks.  So this is just an extension of the answer from Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo.

Since you can't have many object keys with the same name, use an array:

```
declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentInsert('/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article.json',
{ "triples": [
  { "triple": {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/author",
    "object" : "jasonmoore"
  }},
  { "triple": {
    "subject" : "https://content.ea.com/aem/5/content/demo-spark/en_GB/automation_article2.json",
    "predicate" : "https://content.ea.com/iri/id",
    "object" : "automation_article2"
  }},
...
],
  "content" : {
  . . .
  }
});
```

Comment: The subject, predicate, object properties must be wrapped in a property named triple. Apart from that you can put such object anywhere, in a property named triples with an array of such triple objects, or other names properties called triple1, triple2, etc. As long as there is that wrapping property named triple.